# How can i use the az consumption usage list for Azure?

Tags: azure

I am running the following :

```
  az consumption usage list --query "[?properties.instanceLocation=='swedensouth'].{Resource:properties.instanceName, Cost:properties.pretaxCost}" --output table
```

But get the warning :

```
":az : WARNING: Command group 'consumption' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus"


ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01
```

and there is no output.
How can i get the consumption or cost per location from Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used below script to get consumption details for a specific location and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/usage?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az login
$rithcost = az consumption usage list --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails' && instanceLocation=='Asia'].pretaxCost" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
$rithtest = $rithcost -split "`n" | ForEach-Object { [decimal]$_ }
$combcost = $rithtest | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
Write-Host "Total Cost: $combcost"
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: I have tried this and it always gives a Total Cost of 0 ?

Comment: Not Sure why you are getting 0 as you can clearly see in my output i am getting the cost of my resources @Melissa, try using different location May be the location you are using there might be no resources

Comment: I know that there are resources there  as i can go to the azure portal and see them

Comment: I get a warning:  az : WARNING: Command group 'consumption' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus

Comment: its just a warning, it doesnt effect, you are getting warning as its still in preview

Comment: ye but whay am i getting 0 ,, can i analysis and just get the resources in the location first ?

Comment: even if i take out && instanceLocation=='North Central US' , i still get 0

Comment: To get resources use this ```$rithcost = az consumption usage list --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails'&& instanceLocation=='Asia']" --output json```

Comment: get an error:    
ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01

Comment: do i need to put api-version somewhere ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257003/discussion-between-rithwikbojja-and-melissa).